# Проблемы с рекурсия в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

Вот есть простая функция --->

```js
function my_function(n) {
  if (n != 0) {
    return my_function(n - 1) + " " + n;
  }
}

console.log(my_function(9))
```

Вывод будет такой: undefined 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9.

---

Объясните пожалуйста откуда берется undefined в начале и почему исправив код на представленный ниже, он выводит последовательность нормально, без undefined?

```js
function my_function(n) {
  if (n == 1)
    return '1'

  return my_function(n - 1) + ' ' + n;
}

console.log(my_function(9));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  function my_function(n) {
            if (n != 0){
             return   my_function(n-1) + " " + n; 
            }
        }

    my_function(9);
```

Функция будет вызываться до тех пор, пока не выполнится  `my_function(0)`, инструкция `return` находится внутри условия, куда естественно не попадаем -  функция возвращает `undefined`.

Второй вариант возвращает значение в любом случае.